# Bind Range attribute to a Property

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, attributes

In my VM I have some properties validated with the Range attribute like this

```
[Range(50, 800, ErrorMessage = "Value for {0} must be between {1} and {2}.")]
public int TakeOffFlowLevelThreshold { get; set; }
```

Now I want to use some up/down spinner control like

```
<xctk:IntegerUpDown Maximum="{Binding XXXXXX}"/>
```

where XXXXXX is the Maximum of the Range of TakeOffFlowLevelThreshold.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I don see any binding technique, other than using the converter .